# Notation in Ehrenfeucht's games original paper on

Tags: logic, model-theory

Ehrenfeucht's ["An application of games to the completeness problem for formalized theories"](https://eudml.org/doc/213582) gives a language that is similar to weak second order logic, but I'm not sure (see the very start of the paper until rule of formation 5).

There is a notation that troubles me. He uses $\hat x \eta (x)$ to refer to the universe of interpretation (?). Then he uses the notation $\text{stsf}_M \alpha$ for what I believe is $M \models \alpha$.

I wouldn't make much of a problem from these. But I couldn't decipher this one, appearing in page 132, before the proof of what seems the main theorem, theorem 1: $s(x) = S(x) \cap \hat x \text{stsf}_M \eta(x)$.

Could you explain what is this $s(x)$?

Here is $S(x)=
\begin{cases}
\{x\} & \text { if } \mathfrak{M} \models \eta(x), \\
\text{ the least set } Y \text{ such that } x \in Y \text{ and if } z \in Y, t \in z \text{ then } t \in Y, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

See page 129: $\eta(x)$ is a *unary* (one variable) predicate and $\hat x \eta (x)$ is a set, i.e. the set $\{ x \mid \eta (x) \}$.

The author uses it as domain of the interpretation for all formulas of predicate calculus built up using identity, $\in$ and predicates in $A$.

If $\alpha$ is a closed formula, the *satisfaction* relation is denoted with $\mathscr {stsf}_{\mathfrak M} \alpha$, what we usually write as $\mathfrak M \vDash \alpha$.

Given a model $\mathfrak M$ [see page 129: models have domain $|\mathfrak M|$ such that the domain is the smallest set containing the set $\hat x \eta (x)$], the author defines a function $S(x)$ for every element $x$ of the domain of $\mathfrak M$ with the formula above (page 132). What does it mean?

If the "object" $x$ of $|\mathfrak M|$ satisfies predicate $\eta(x)$, then the value of function $S(x)$ is the set $\{ x \}$, with $x$ as single element. If not, the other option will be used.